# Received error Attempted import error: 'NotificationsNoneIcon' is not exported from '@material-ui/icons'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to write my code, I imported my css file but it doesn't while its address is correct , also I receive this error :

```
./src/components/topbar/Topbar.jsx
Attempted import error: 'NotificationsNoneIcon' is not exported from '@material-ui/icons'.
```

While I ran these commands :

```
npm install @material-ui/core
npm install @material-ui/icons
```

Here is my code : could you help me ?

```
import React from 'react';
import './topbar.css';
import {NotificationsNoneIcon} from '@material-ui/icons';

    function Topbar() {
        return (
            <div className="topbar">
                <div className="topbarWrapper">
                    <div className="topleft">
                        <span className="logo">lammadamin</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="topright">
                        <div className="topbarIcons">
                            <NotificationsNoneIcon/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Topbar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import NotificationsNone instead of NotificationsNoneIcon

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is you tried to import from `@material-ui/icons` while the documentation suggests `@material-ui/icons/NotificationsNone` to do so.

Based on the documentation you should import as:

```
import NotificationsNoneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/NotificationsNone'
```

Read further here:
https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/